# How to save an avi with a time stamp in real time using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, video, timestamp

I presently have a gui that captures avi file. It works as follows:

[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzVVH.png)

The image in the controller is the preview from the camera. When I push the Start Record button, the program will catch the image with getsnapshot() function and writeVideo() function to write the image to a video file.

And I get time information with clock function after the getsnapshot() function. (I find when use [frame, metadata] = getsnapshot(obj), metadata is empty. I do not know why).

I want to ask if I can save the time information to the video file, (e.g., avi file) in real time. I do not know how to do it. Anyone has ideas?

Comment: Your comments below are a little confusing, Are you having trouble getting timing data for each frame? Do you want the time stamp displayed on the image itself? Or do you want to add the timing data to the movie file without modifying the image frames?

Comment: Hi, gnovice. Thank you very much for continuous help. Can I add the timing data to the movie file without modifying the image frames? I do not know how to do it. And I also confused by the time information of the video. I found when use getdata(), the time interval of frames is very well-distributed, it may be the sampling rate of the camera. But when use getsapshot(), the time is not thus well-distributed (may be because I call other functions after the getsapshot, the program like this while(true) im=getsapshot(); timestamp=clock; other functions; VideoWriter();...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any way to add custom header fields to an AVI file to store your additional time information. However, you *could* add an extra row to the bottom of your image frame that contains the encoded time stamp information for that frame. This will depend on the format of your `frame` data, but here's an example to illustrate:

Let's say `frame` is your typical [RGB (Truecolor) image](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-12468), with three color planes and [`uint8`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html) data values, like the built-in sample image `'peppers.png'`:

```
img = imread('peppers.png');
```

[image]

The [`clock`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clock.html) function returns the current data and time as a date vector, which is a six-element [double-precision](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) vector. This requires 48 bytes of storage. We can cast the 1-by-6 `double` vector to a 1-by-48 `uint8` vector using the [`typecast`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) function, then add it to the beginning of an additional row of the red image plane (padding the rest of the row and other planes with zeroes automatically):

```
img(end+1, 1:48, 1) = typecast(clock, 'uint8');
```

The extra row at the bottom is fairly inconspicuous:

[image]

And we can reconstitute the time stamp and original image like so:

```
t = typecast(img(end, 1:48, 1), 'double');
img = img(1:(end-1), :, :);
```

Comment: Hi. gnovice. Thanks very much for the help. Actually, I added a time stamp as your way, but I transform the data to image. Like the image shown in follows.

Comment: Can I use getdata() to record video in real time. But I find getdata() is really slow when I record. Only get 2 frames per second... And I found getsnapshot() looses some frames (not much, it is OK) during record.

Comment: Hi, gnovice. Thank you very much for continuous help. Can I add the timing data to the movie file without modifying the image frames? I do not know how to do it. And I also confused by the time information of the video. I found when use getdata(), the time interval of frames is very well-distributed, it may be the sampling rate of the camera. But when use getsapshot(), the time is not thus well-distributed (may be because I call other functions after the getsapshot, the program like this while(true) im=getsapshot(); timestamp=clock; other functions; VideoWriter();...).

Comment: Can I write all information in one file, including the video, timestamp, etc.

Comment: Hi, gnovice. I hava another problem. When I use your method, I find the number is changed after write to the video file. I do not know why. I also try to add a black area at the bottom of the image. But When I read it from the video with VideoReader. I find the values of the black area are not always 0. Is it possible that the writeVideo function changes the value during writing the frame to the video?

Comment: I find the problem, it caused by the compression...When I use Uncompressed AVI, the image is not distortion and the time stamp by gnovice is good. But when use Motion JPEG AVI, it is distortion.